# Copy ctor not Operating as Expected in VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I have a small class for performing basic/lightweight matrix operations.

```
template<class E, int Rows, int Cols>
class TinyExpression {
public:
    static const int ROWS = Rows;
    static const int COLS = Cols;

    inline const E& operator () () const 
    {
        return *static_cast<const E*> (this);
    }
    inline E& operator () () 
    {
        return *static_cast<E*> (this);
    }
protected:
    TinyExpression() {}
    ~TinyExpression() {}
private:
    const TinyExpression& operator=(const TinyExpression &);
    TinyExpression(const TinyExpression&);
};

template <class M, int Rows, int Cols>
class TinyNegate : public TinyExpression<TinyNegate<M, Rows, Cols>, Rows, Cols>
{
public:
    typedef typename M::value_type value_type;
    TinyNegate(const M& m) : _m(m) {};
    inline int size() const { return _m.size(); }
    inline int size1() const { return _m.size1(); }
    inline int size2() const { return _m.size2(); }
    inline value_type operator()(int r, int c) const { return -_m(r, c); }
private:
    const M& _m;
};
```

In my `TinyMatrix` class I have

```
template <int Rows, int Cols>
class TinyMatrix : public TinyExpression<TinyMatrix<Rows, Cols>, Rows, Cols>
{
public:
    typedef double value_type;

    TinyMatrix()
    {
        std::fill(_data, _data + Rows * Cols, 0.0);
    }

    TinyMatrix(const TinyMatrix<Rows, Cols>& m) 
    {
        std::copy(m.begin(), m.begin() + size(), &_data[0]);
    }

    ... // Lots of other stuff.

    TinyNegate<TinyMatrix<Rows, Cols>, Rows, Cols> operator-() const
    {
        return TinyNegate<TinyMatrix<Rows, Cols>, Rows, Cols>(*this); // THIS IS THE OFFENDING LINE
    }
}
```

The offending code is marked and is `return TinyNegate<TinyMatrix<Rows, Cols>, Rows, Cols>(*this);`. This code was working fine in VS2013, now in VS2015 it does not compile with the following error

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C2280   'TinyNegate,2,1>::TinyNegate(const TinyNegate,2,1> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function  MyProject   f:\src\math\matrix\tiny_matrix.h    126

But I am correctly defining an explicit copy constructor using a reference value. I could not use the copy-ctor and use direct initialization but this would give me obvious errors regarding my `const` types. This worked in VS2013 and on gcc...

What evil is the new C++ compiler that ships with VS2015 doing, why am I getting this error and how can I fix this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Looks like the private unimplemented copy constuctor/assignment operators have been silently 'deleted'...

Comment: Are there any other error messages following this one? I am not sure about Visual Studio, but recent versions of gcc give usually more information with this type of error.

Comment: @MarkusParker unfortunately no. This is all the compiler is spitting out.

Comment: @Killercam In the mean time I copied your code into a new Visual Studio project and got an addition line, which gives the hint that the actual copy constructor is not defined and, since there is a member of a reference type, deleted: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error (active)  function "TinyNegate<M, Rows, Cols>::TinyNegate(const TinyNegate<TinyMatrix<1, 2>, 1, 2> &) [with M=TinyMatrix<1, 2>, Rows=1, Cols=2]" (declared implicitly) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message does not refer to the constructor

```
TinyNegate(const M& m) : _m(m) {};
```

which is in fact *not* a copy constructor. The actual copy constructor looks like

```
TinyNegate(const TinyNegate& t) : _m(t._m) {};
```

Add it and the code should compile. Note that you do not need to specify the template parameters for the argument type `TinyNegate`.

Comment: This will not compile due to the `const` value of `_m`.

Comment: It does compile. I tried it. _m is const, but this does not mean I cannot initialize it (see the first constructor) as in **_m** (t._m) or access it as in _m(**t._m**).

Comment: If it does not compile in your case, maybe you can post the error message?

Comment: Okay, we don't have to call it a "copy constructor" in the truest sense, but I want the `TinyNegate` ctor to copy my `TinyMatrix` not operate on the `TinyNegate` itself. The call to `return TinyNegate<TinyMatrix<Rows, Cols>, Rows, Cols>(*this)` is acting on a `TinyMatrix` so `TinyNegate(const M& m) : _m(m) {};` should work. The `TinyNegate(const TinyNegate& t) : _m(t._m) {};` is indeed a true "copy ctor" but this is not what I want. Please excuse my loose terminology in the first instance. Oh, and thanks again for your time it is most appreciated.